# Unable to add a Microsoft account after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: user-accounts, windows-10-upgrade

After upgrading to WIndows 10 I am unable to add a Microsoft account nor am I able to add a new user.  The screen just flashes. Others have reported this problem. It will let me add a "work" account but does not accept the emails that the other users have (gmail hotmail etc.)

The Microsoft account login credentials  are recognized, however, if I connect to onedrive or other Microsoft programs AFTER logging on Admin.

I tried suggested fixes such as editing the Microsoft identities in the registry.

This problem ios only affecting the Windows 10 machine, other versions continue to work as before./

Thanks for you help.

Comment: An additional observation. While I am able to access my One Drive files I am not able to open my One Notes. I have also noticed that there is huge  (60 percent or more) CPU use frombackground processes, especially Runtime Broker. Are these two issues connected? I am going to try disabline ONe Drive and see what that does, but I can't really function without it....